# How to add Drawer for SliverAppBar

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

This is my code, copied from [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html):

```
SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: 150.0,
  flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
      title: Text('Available seats'),
    ),
    actions: < Widget > [
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
          tooltip: 'Add new entry',
          onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
      ),
    ]
)
```

But I need to add a `Drawer`. How can I do that?
I am trying to rebuild my app in Flutter.
[Converting java android  app to flutter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.midhilaj_m.mypetshop&hl=en)

I replaced the icon but how can I create a `Drawer`?

```
leading: IconButton(icon: Icon( Icons.menu ),onPressed: ()=>{},)
```

My full code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () => {},
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              )
            ],
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Text("My Pet Shop",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    )),
                background: Image.network(
                  "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-pet-world.appspot.com/o/images%2Fbannerads%2FxTmAblJI7fMF1l0nUa1gM32Kh9z1%2F734rm6w7bxznp%2FPETWORLD-HOME-SLIDER-KITTENS.webp?alt=media&token=cf7f48bb-6621-47b3-b3f8-d8b36fa89715",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              //getHomePageWidget()
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                children: <Widget>[getHomePageWidget()],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ));
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to manually added the menu icon in your SliverAppBar. The menu icon will appear magically when you have Scaffold as its ancestor.

Comment: can you please update with my new given code

Comment: where to add Scaffold  in my new code?

Comment: I just did. Your body code had a lot of unnecessary codes, so I just stripped all of them and was left with getHomePageWidget().

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Drawer is a property for Scaffold. Once you set a drawer property, the menu icon will automatically appear in the SliverAppBar.

Return this inside your build method, and you will get what you are looking for.

```
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 200.0,
          flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text('Available seats'),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
              tooltip: 'Add new entry',
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
            getHomePageWidget(),
          ]),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    drawer: Drawer(),
  );
```

NOTE: if you have multiple `Scaffold` in the tree above the `CustomScrollView` than the `Drawer` should be in the most bottom `Scaffold`

Comment: @Midhilaj Sorry, I had some mistake in my code. I just edited it and now it should work!

Comment: let me check it

Comment: @Midhilaj Let me know how it goes

Comment: @Midhilaj what do you mean?

Comment: @Midhilaj The code you provided is still not the full code. Can I see the entire build function?

Comment: @Midhilaj I forgot to include it in my final code, but those problems should be solved by changing floating property or the pinned property of the SliverAppBar. Good luck!

Comment: You are great at 11:48 pm you helped me and no my friends do this help

Comment: @Midhilaj Any time, my friend and happy new Year!

Comment: Happy New Year .